TouchListener works only once after enabling zoom in Android webview
The simplified version of the code I wrote:
    //Enable zoom.
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();  
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

    //Set TouchListener
    webView.setOnTouchListener(this::onTouchWebView);
    .
    .
    .

    // TouchListener
    boolean onTouchWebView(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            ...
        }
    }

MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, etc. are passed to the onTouchWebView() function at the first touch of Android phone screen. However, the onTouchWebView() function is never called from the second screen touch.
If zoom is disabled onTouchWebView() function works very well!!!
How can I solve this problem?
My programming environment is as follows:
Android Studio: 2023.3.1
Compile Sdk: 34
target Sdk:  34
I would like to express my gratitude in advance while waiting for the great masters to teach me.
Sincerely yours.

Possibly relevant questions are 1) Why are the built-in zoom controls needed? Isn't regular pinch zoom enough or doesn't it work? 2) Why is a TouchListener on the WebView needed? Doesn't the WebView content (HTML, Javascript etc.) react to touch events in the desired way? Maybe these things help people suggesting ways to solve this.

I could solved this problem by myself. I appended following code:
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

After that touch listener works well.
